# Is the diffusion of wave packets in time according to Schrödinger due to the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, schroedinger-equation, diffusion

I hope this isn't too much of a 'why' question. Let's imagine we measure at time $t=0$ the momentum of a free non-relativistic particle with positive mass in 1D. What we find is a certain momentum $p_0$, so we can say that at time $t \geq 0 $ our particle is in the state $| \psi(t) \rangle$ defined by $$\langle x | \psi(t) \rangle=\int g(p,t)e^{ipx/\hbar} \mathrm{d}p$$

with $g(.,t=0)$ a certain funcion with support contained between $p_0-\Delta p$ and $p_0+\Delta p$, with $\Delta p$ being the uncertainty due to the measuring apparatus. According to the Schrödinger equation, the wave-packet will diffuse, i.e. the support of $g(.,t)$ will grow with time, so that we know less and less  what the momentum of our particle is. What is the physical intuition for this fact?

Is it because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle? Indeed if I know the momentum (hence velocity) of the particle at time $t=0$, reasoning semi-classically I can deduce how the position of the particle will evolve at least in the near future, so in some sense I get an information on the position. I don't really know how to use it since I don't know the position at $t=0$, but I would guess the information becomes more and more useful because the initial position of the particle becomes negligible compared to the change in position due to the initial velocity after a long time (if I know the velocity at $t=0$ is positive in the direction $e_x$, after a long time I'm almost sure that the particle is right of $x=0$, even if I don't know anything about the position at $t=0$), which is why I lose more and more information about the momentum.

I don't know if this makes too much sense. Does it? If not, is there a way to understand why the Schrödinger equation make wave packets diffuse?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *why* questions.

Comment: What does $g(.,t=0)$ really stand for?

Comment: It stands for the function $p \mapsto g(p,0)$.

Comment: *almost sure that the particle is right of =0* this is true if support of $g$ is positive. Regardless of its size. So can it really be due to uncertainty?

Comment: @Gert it is the state in momentum basis. $g(p)=\langle p|\psi\rangle$

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish I think you are confusing position and momentum

Comment: I mean to know $x>0$  all you need to know is that momentum is positive irrespective of how spread out the momentum is.

Comment: Ah yes sorry. Maybe for this particular fact, yes, but I just meant to give an example of how I imagined one could exploit the initial information about the velocity to gain information about the position. Maybe a more precise probe would be to have the quantum particle compete with a classical body going at a certain speed and decide wether the quantum particle is right or left of the body after a long time. But anyways I'm not sure about the value of these examples.

Comment: Why would the wavepacket diffuse in momentum space? The Hamiltonian is diagonal in momentum basis. Diffusion requires a matrix with off-diagonals. The wavepacket diffuses in position space only.

Comment: @Dwagg So i was the confusing momentum and position, sorry.  So why is there diffusion in QM?

Comment: Well, a term $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in the Hamiltonian always gives rise to something akin to diffusion in position space. This term is seen all the time in QM. Some people have noted that the free particle Schrodinger equation is equivalent to the diffusion equation with $t\to it$. There may be something more to say about that, but I'm not sure.